# Flat griddle pan for Weber Spirit II E-320 BBQ

Tags: barbecue

I'm trying to buy a flat griddle pan for a Weber Spirit II E-320 Gas BBQ and not sure what will fit/what is compatible.

Currently I have [these cooking grates](https://www.weber.com/GB/en/accessories/cleaning-and-care/replacement-parts---gas/8847.html?cgid=2035#start=1) installed:

[image]

So I'm not sure if:

- a. There's a flat griddle pan that will replace one or more of those grates.
- b. You're supposed to have the flat pan sit on top of those grates.
- c. I need to buy separate grates that are compatible with a flat griddle.

I'd also preferably get a “knock-off” version of the pan for cheaper as the Weber ones are very expensive.

Comment: Hi everybody, I would like to remind you that we don't accept answers in comments. If you want to say that one of the points a), b) or c) is true, please do so in an answer, not in a comment. Also, shopping advice that suggests specific makes and models of things to buy is out of scope, so such a post would not be just a partial answer (which in itself would be fully acceptable, and no reason to use a comment) but probably the most complete answer you can give anyway.

Comment: What’s the diameter of the circular cutout?  Because you might be able to use accessories for the STOK Quattro grill: https://www.stokgrills.com/products/inserts

Answer (score 4):

b.  Make it easy and less expensive by putting a cast iron pan on top of the grates.  Thats what I do.  I have a Genesis and just put a regular round cast iron pan on top of the grates. I know there are flat griddle style cast iron pans that you could do the same with.  It does get hot enought to smoke off the "seasoning".  I learned to do this at a restuarant I was grill cook at in order to make blackened steaks.

Answer (score 1):

For (a), the replacement part is just called [Griddle](https://www.weber.com/US/en/accessories/accessories-by-category/tools--et--cookware/griddle-7421/7421.html).

Since the question links to the Great Britain locale, here is the [GB version](https://www.weber.com/GB/en/accessories/cooking/weber-crafted-gourmet-bbq-system/7421.html). I noticed that when browsing the GB site, I did not find this griddle in the Griddle section which may be part of the problem leading to this question. This link was generated by just changing US to GB from the US url.

The description notes (**emphasis added**):

> Fits WEBER CRAFTED cooking grates and frame kit for SMOKEFIRE EX4/EX6/EPX6 wood pellet grills and GENESIS 2022, GENESIS 2016+ and **SPIRIT 2016+ gas grills**

So if you have a recent Spirit, it should fit. The handles fit into the horizontal cutouts of the grates instead of the vertical cutouts the circular grate fits into.

I have the E-210 with similar grates (2 rectangular with semi-circular cutout and a 3rd circular, likely just narrower rectangular grates) that came in bundle with the Griddle. I have not used it so I can not comment on functionality versus other alternatives.